# Put rows together in result of query?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

This little problem is driving up the wall... I have this table:

```
ID  N1  N2  N3
----------------------------------------------
1     -     2     -

1     9     -     -

1     -     -     3

2     -     -     2

2     1     -     -

3     -     -     -

3     1     -     3
```

and I want this result:

```
ID  N1  N2  N3
-----------------------------
1     9     2     3

2     1     -     2

3     1     -     3
```

I mean, I want to put rows together depending on the ID and preserving the data that is not null in the other columns, in Oracle...

Please help me! I don't know much about PL/SQL but I imagine that the solution could be found by using functions or procedures.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410456/sql-filtering-out-less-specific-rows) please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using min, this can be achieved

```
with tab(ID,N1,N2,N3) as (
select 1,NULL,2,NULL from dual union all
select 1,9,NULL,NULL from dual union all
select 1,NULL,NULL,3 from dual union all
select 2,NULL,NULL,2 from dual union all
select 2,1,NULL,NULL from dual union all
select 3,NULL,NULL,NULL from dual union all
select 3,1,NULL,3 from dual)
-----
--End of data
-----
select id, min(n1), min(n2), min(n3) 
  from tab
  group by id
```

Output

```
| ID | MIN(N1) | MIN(N2) | MIN(N3) |
|----|---------|---------|---------|
|  1 |       9 |       2 |       3 |
|  2 |       1 |  (null) |       2 |
|  3 |       1 |  (null) |       3 |
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Could you please reommend me a step by step tutorial or a reference guide for the statements?

Comment: You can refer [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php) for basic understanding of Oracle statements and functions. In this query, I have grouped all the rows on ID and from each group I am selecting the minimum value for n1, n2 and n3. Since for a particular group only one row has a values(rest are null), it will show up in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those "-" represent values that are null, you could use the FIRST_VALUE analytical function, with the IGNORE NULLS option.

Example Query:

```
select id, 
first_value(n1) ignore nulls over (partition by n1 order by n1) as N1, 
first_value(n2) ignore nulls over (partition by n2 order by n2) as N2, 
first_value(n3) ignore nulls over (partition by n3 order by n3) as N3 
from table;
```

More information on the function can be found [on Oracle Base](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

How about simply grouping the records with `MIN` or `MAX`(depending on your requirement) values for columns `N1`, `N2`, `N3`

```
SELECT id, MIN(n1), MIN(n2), MIN(n3) 
FROM   <table_name>
GROUP BY id;
```